How to get data hourly, daily and monthly
I have data from https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/api/explore/v2.1/catalog/datasets/sensor-readings-with-temperature-light-humidity-every-5-minutes-at-8-locations-t/exports/csv?lang=en&timezone=Europe%2FHelsinki&use_labels=true&delimiter=%2C
The dataframe looks like this:
enter image description here
**I have converted the timestamp to datatime64 **
#  Inspect the data
print(df['timestamp'].head(5))
print(df['timestamp'].dtype)

# Attempt conversion with specific format + Handle potential timezone issues
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z', utc=True)
print(df['timestamp'].dtype)

# Check for missing or invalid data
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce')
print(df['timestamp'].dtype)

#  Convert to string representation
df['timestamp_str'] = df['timestamp'].astype(str)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_str'])
print(df['timestamp'].dtype)

Task
I need to calculate Median, SD and Dropout rate, without using Pandas function like median() or std() (it is stupid but its a homework). I think I need all data groupby according to hourly, daily and monthly.
How do I get the all data for hourly, daily and monthly?
I have tried the below:
every_freq = df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.floor(freq)).first 

Only the first row of each hour and day will be kept.

If you want to group your data by hours, days, or months using groupby, you can try groupby with pd.Grouper. This allows you to maintain all your data within each group, rather than just keeping the first row like you would with .first().
# Grouping by hourly frequency
hourly_groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='H'))

# Grouping by daily frequency
daily_groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='D'))

# Grouping by monthly frequency
monthly_groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='M'))

An alternative would be to use resample which is purposely designed for working with time series data, instead of groupby which is more general-purpose.
hourly_data = df.resample('h', on='timestamp')
daily_data = df.resample('D', on='timestamp')
monthly_data = df.resample('ME', on='timestamp')

The code was tested on Pandas version 2.2.2.

Use resample.median/mean/std/...:
# ensure to have the timestamp as index
df = pd.read_csv('sensor-readings-with-temperature-light-humidity-every-5-minutes-at-8-locations-t.csv',
                 index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True)

# hours
df.resample('H').median(numeric_only=True)

# days
df.resample('D').median(numeric_only=True)

# month
df.resample('MS').median(numeric_only=True)

Output:
                           boardtype  boardid  temp_max  temp_min  temp_avg  \
timestamp                                                                     
2014-12-15 01:00:00+00:00        1.0    505.0     21.60     21.60     21.60   
2014-12-15 02:00:00+00:00        1.0    504.5     22.55     22.55     22.55   
2014-12-15 03:00:00+00:00        1.0    508.5     23.50     23.50     23.50   
2014-12-15 04:00:00+00:00        1.0    509.0     22.90     22.90     22.90   
2014-12-15 05:00:00+00:00        1.0    509.0     21.30     21.30     21.30   
...                              ...      ...       ...       ...       ...   
2015-06-05 00:00:00+00:00        1.0    509.0      7.70      7.70      7.70   
2015-06-05 01:00:00+00:00        1.0    509.0      7.70      7.70      7.70   
2015-06-05 02:00:00+00:00        1.0    509.0      7.70      7.70      7.70   
2015-06-05 03:00:00+00:00        1.0    509.0      7.70      7.70      7.70   
2015-06-05 04:00:00+00:00        1.0    509.0      8.10      8.10      8.10   


You can use resample() on a datetime index to aggregate to another frequency.
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
df.resample('M').mean()

This gives one record per month containing the mean value for every numerical column. You can also use other aggregation functions such as first, max, sd, etc.
To get hourly data, resample on 'H', and 'D' for daily.
